# iPhone 3.0 telephone hyperlinks can't be cancelled?

Tags: iphone, uiwebview

I just noticed that since the upgrade to 3.0 the meta-tag:

```
<meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no" />
```

Stopped working in my application. I'm using a UIWebView and everything worked before the upgrade. Any ideas? Anyone else having this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried setting the UIDataDetectorType for the UIWebView?

```
webView.dataDetectorTypes = UIDataDetectorTypeLink;
```

**UIDataDetectorTypes**:

Defines the types of information that can be detected in text-based content.

**Types**:

- UIDataDetectorTypePhoneNumber;
- UIDataDetectorTypeLink;
- UIDataDetectorTypeNone;
- UIDataDetectorTypeAll;